# Python- Preciso fazer um aplicativo que receba valores float e organize os mesmos sem ultilizar o .sort

Tags: python

Até agora eu consegui fazer o seguinte:

```
lista = []
a = 1
b = 0
while a > 0:
    a = float(input("Colque os valores: "))
    b = b + 1
    for i in range (b):
        lista.append(a)
n = len(lista)
for i in range(n-1):
    for j in range(n-1):
        if lista[i] > lista[i+1]:
            lista[i], lista[i+1] = lista[i+1], lista[i]
lista.reverse()
print("Primeiro lugar: ", lista[0], "Segundo lugar: ", lista[1], "Terceiro lugar: ", lista[2])
```

Porém o codigo em questão não está funcionando corretamente, consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

@soaresde, acredito que você esteja querendo implementar um `bubble sort`, certo?

Tem dois probleminhas com seu script:

1. Entrada de dados
2. Loop de ordenação

### Entrada de dados

```
while a > 0:
    a = float(input("Colque os valores: "))
    if a > 0:
        lista.append(a)
```

### Loop de ordenação

```
for num in range(n-1,0,-1):
    for i in range(num):
        if lista[i]>lista[i+1]:
            lista[i], lista[i+1] = lista[i+1], lista[i]
```

Perceba que o loop de fora "anda de costas", enquanto o de dentro "anda de frente" e a partir no número `num`

### Exemplo

```
>>> lista = [4.3, 2.1, 3.5, -1.7, 0.1, -6.2, 5.4, 7.5, 9.1, 8.4]
>>> n = len(lista)

>>> for num in range(n-1,0,-1):
...     for i in range(num):
...         if lista[i]>lista[i+1]:
...             lista[i], lista[i+1] = lista[i+1], lista[i]
...

>>> lista
[-6.2, -1.7, 0.1, 2.1, 3.5, 4.3, 5.4, 7.5, 8.4, 9.1]
```

Mesmo o seu script não aceitando números negativos, o `bubble sort` aceitaria os mesmos sem problemas.

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma de resolver esta questão é utilizando o algoritmo de ordenação **shell_sort**.

Para implementarmos este algoritmo devemos:

1. Capturar os valores que serão montados na lista;
2. Ordenar os valores da referida lista;
3. Exibir os valores ordenados.

Desta forma temos:

```
def shell_sort(v):
    h = len(v) // 2
    while h > 0:
        i = h
        while i < len(v):
            temp = v[i]
            troca = False
            j = i - h
            while (j >= 0) and (v[j] > temp):
                v[j + h] = v[j]
                troca = True
                j -= h
            if troca:
                v[j + h] = temp
            i += 1
        h = h // 2

    return v[-1], v[-2], v[-3]


lista = list(map(float, input('Digite os valores: ').split()))

prim, seg, terc = shell_sort(lista)

print(f'O primeiro lugar é: {prim}\nO segundo lugar é: {seg}\nO terceiro lugar é: {terc}')
```

Observe que quando executamos este código recebemos a mensagem: `Digite os valores`. Neste momento devemos digitar **todos** os valores, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar `Enter`.

A partir deste momento o código realizará todo o trabalho de ordenação.

**Testando o código:**

se desejamos montar uma lista com **8** valores do tiplo **float** e em seguida, ordena-los, devemos:

Digitar os valores...

```
4.6 8.2 3.4 2.2 -6.7 -3.3 6.7 8.8
```

...e pressionar `enter`. Então, a saída será...

```
O primeiro lugar é: 8.8
O segundo lugar é: 8.2
O terceiro lugar é: 6.7
```