# Como ordenar uma lista em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou resolvendo um exercício em Python que pede para ordenar uma lista com 5 valores digitados pelo usuário em ordem crescente, sem utilizar o método sort(). O problema é que o meu código não está funcionando como deveria. O erro que está acontecendo é que em vez dele imprimir todos os valores ordenados, ele só imprime alguns. Por exemplo, se eu digitar 7, 4, 2, 8, 3 ele imprime [2, 4, 7, 8, 3].
Gostaria de saber em qual parte eu errei. Segue o meu código:

```
listaNumeros = []

for i in range(0, 5):
   numero = int(input('Digite um número: '))

if i == 0:
    listaNumeros.append(numero)
else:
    for j in range(0, len(listaNumeros)):
        if numero < listaNumeros[j]:
            listaNumeros.insert(j, numero)
            break
        else:
            if numero > listaNumeros[j]:
                listaNumeros.append(numero)
                break

print(listaNumeros)
```

Comment: Veja se este [post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/479790/python-preciso-fazer-um-aplicativo-que-receba-valores-float-e-organize-os-mesmo) ajuda.

Comment: [Algoritmos de ordenação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o#:~:text=Algoritmo%20de%20ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20em%20ci%C3%AAncia,para%20se%20ordenar%20uma%20sequ%C3%AAncia.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para resolver esta questão você pode implementar o algoritmo de ordenação **Bubble sort**.

Para implementar o Bubble sort nesta questão devemos:

1. Capturar os valores que montarão a lista;
2. Ordenar estes valores;
3. Exibir os valores ordenados.

Com esta lógica o código ficaria:

```
def bubble_sort(v):
    fim = len(v)
    while fim > 0:
        i = 0
        while i < fim - 1:
            if v[i] > v[i + 1]:
                v[i], v[i + 1] = v[i + 1], v[i]
            i += 1
        fim -= 1
    return v


listaNumeros = list()
for c in range(1, 6):
    listaNumeros.append(int(input(f'Digite o {c}º valor: ')))

print(bubble_sort(listaNumeros))
```

Observe que quando executamos este código devemos digitar cada um dos **5** valores. Depois o código irá executar a ordenação.

**Como ocorre esta ordenação?**

O primeiro bloco **while** percorre todos os valores possíveis de tamanho da lista em ordem decrescente. Enquanto o tamanho da lista for maior que zero o **2º bloco while** percorre a lista **v** de **0 até fim** e o bloco **if** realiza a troca do valor atual pelo próximo. Em seguida **i** é incrementado e a variável **fim** é decrementada.

Terminada a ordenação, a lista será exibida.

**Testando o código**

Imagine que queremos ordenar os cinco valores seguintes; 6, 4, 3, 5 e 8. Neste caso, executamos o código e digitamos;

```
6
4
3
5
8
```

Pressionamos `Enter` e, a saída será:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, 8]
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, estudei esse código e fiquei tentando montar igual ao seu. Funcionou direitinho!

Comment: Eu só não entendi o primeiro while. Porque a leitura tem que acontecer do final para o começo da lista?